# concerns about something raised vs concerns raised about something

Tags: sentence-construction

> If you do decide to take an EPA/DHA supplement, I suggest choosing a
> vegan version, rather than fish oil. They are free of the *concerns
> about impurities and odor raised* by many fish oil brands.

Since I know for a fact that the concerns are not "raised by many fish oil brands", shouldn't 'raised' come right after 'concerns'?:

> They are free of the *concerns raised about impurities and odor* by
> many fish oil brands.

I googled "concerns raised about", and it's been used and seems correct. So is the original sentence correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alternative you have suggested, "concerns raised about..." can be rephrased to "concerns that are raised about..." So the main noun isn't immediately followed by the *"about"* clause, which could be misleading but it doesn't change the intended meaning.

It may not be stylistically correct in some people's eyes. It's just a matter of approach sometimes and how you decide to interpret words to form a sentence.

The original sentence is correct as it is.

Personally, I recommend saying: *concerns about ... raised ...*

Comment: Thank you very much Alex. Just one more thing: Does 'by' here mean 'concerning' (Oxford/Lexico, 7) or 'with respect to' (Merriam-Webster, 8a)?

Comment: @Nima Abna Neither compute. "by" here identifies the agent performing an action as in *"The door was opened **by** my brother."* You are very welcome :)

Comment: Oh right! I came to that conclusion because I was expecting to see something like "produced by" or "in products by".